# Where is the source code for NSObject.m?

Tags: cocoa, open-source

I'm trying to find the source for `NSObject.m`. (I want to compare the pre and post ARC implementations of `retain` and `release`.)

I've looked on http://www.opensource.apple.com/ and http://www.macosforge.org/ but not been able to find it.

Comment: Why do you think that it would be open sourced?

Comment: @sosborn I may be getting confused. I know that most of Core Foundation is open source and that Foundation/Cocoa are based on OpenStep, which GNUStep is also based on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The source code for Apple's `NSObject` is contained in the Objective-C runtime package on Apple's open source repository site.

https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-706/runtime/NSObject.mm

The whole Objective-C runtime package can be downloaded from https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/objc4/objc4-706.tar.gz

Looking back through the previous versions of the runtime package on the site it appears the `NSObject.mm` file was added in the [objc4-532](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/objc4/objc4-532.tar.gz) package.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for NSObject is available in the Objective-C Runtime (latest version available at the time of this edit) http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-680/runtime/NSObject.mm as noted above. Although Cocoa (Touch) the Framework is not open source if you wanted to see that. Additionally there is another complete implementation of NSObject in the GNUStep Base Package https://github.com/gnustep/base/blob/master/Source/NSObject.m.

Answer (score 1):

I got confused. Apple makes most of Core Foundation (the C API that Foundation/Cocoa is based on) available as open source. Foundation/Cocoa are based on OpenStep. GNUStep is an open source implementation of OpenStep.

The GNUStep implementation on `NSObject.m` can be found at http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Main_Page